# rspec 3.4 test controller concern with response.body.read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following controller concern that is used for authentication:

```
module ValidateEventRequest
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def event_request_verified?(request)
    sha256 = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
    secret = app_client_id
    body = request.body.read
    signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(sha256, secret, body)
    ([signature] & [request.headers['X-Webhook-Signature'], request.headers['X-Api-Signature']]).present?
  end

  private

  def app_client_id
    ENV['APP_CLIENT_ID']
  end
end
```

So far I have the following Rspec Test setup to hit this:

```
RSpec.describe ValidateEventRequest, type: :concern do
  let!(:current_secret) { SecureRandom.hex }

  describe '#event_request_verified?' do
    it 'validates X-Webhook-Signature' do
      # TBD
    end

    it 'validates X-Api-Signature' do
      # TBD
    end
  end
end
```

I started out with stubbing the request, then mocking and stubbing, and now I am down to scrapping what I have and seeking assistance.  100% coverage is important to me and I am looking for some pointers on how to structure tests that cover this 100%.

Comment: So it looks like you learned to test with a language other than rails from your test setup.  In rspec you don't need to make fakes in this manner.  You can just do "RSpec.describe ValidateEventRequest, type: :concern do"  rather than creating a fake.  I am not very familiar with how to test concerns because many in the Ruby community think they are a bad Idea (http://blog.coreyhaines.com/2012/12/why-i-dont-use-activesupportconcern.html, http://mcdowall.info/the-great-satan-rails-concerns/).  That said if you restructure your test as I mentioned you should be able to mock and stub as expected.

Comment: I tried that way the first time, and could not get the stubs and mocks to work correctly.... hmmmm..

Comment: If you want to update your question with your old code and let me know your specific error message I can help you through it.  Personally I don't think you need concerns for this and I would just use a before action.

Comment: @ruby_newbie I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved this issue, and I am open to ideas:

```
RSpec.describe ValidateApiRequest, type: :concern do
  let!(:auth_secret) { ENV['APP_CLIENT_ID'] }
  let!(:auth_sha256) { OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new }
  let!(:auth_body) { 'TESTME' }
  let(:object) { FakeController.new }
  before(:each) do
    allow(described_class).to receive(:secret).and_return(auth_secret)
    class FakeController < ApplicationController
      include ValidateApiRequest
    end
  end

  after(:each) do
    Object.send :remove_const, :FakeController
  end

  describe '#event_request_verified?' do
    context 'X-Api-Signature' do
      it 'pass' do
        request = OpenStruct.new(headers: { 'X-Api-Signature' => OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(auth_sha256, auth_secret, auth_body) }, raw_post: auth_body)
        expect(object.event_request_verified?(request)).to be_truthy
      end

      it 'fail' do
        request = OpenStruct.new(headers: { 'X-Api-Signature' => OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(auth_sha256, 'not-the-same', auth_body) }, raw_post: auth_body)
        expect(object.event_request_verified?(request)).to be_falsey
      end
    end

    context 'X-Webhook-Signature' do
      it 'pass' do
        request = OpenStruct.new(headers: { 'X-Webhook-Signature' => OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(auth_sha256, auth_secret, auth_body) }, raw_post: auth_body)
        expect(object.event_request_verified?(request)).to be_truthy
      end

      it 'fail' do
        request = OpenStruct.new(headers: { 'X-Webhook-Signature' => OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(auth_sha256, 'not-the-same', auth_body) }, raw_post: auth_body)
        expect(object.event_request_verified?(request)).to be_falsey
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`object_double` is handy for testing concerns:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe MyClass do
  subject { object_double(Class.new).tap {|c| c.extend MyClass} }

  it "extends the subject" do
    expect(subject.respond_to?(:some_method_in_my_class)).to be true
    # ...
```

Then you can test `subject` like any other class. Of course you need to pass in the appropriate arguments when testing methods, which may mean creating additional mocks -- in your case a request object.

Comment: I like where this is going, could you adapt your example to my posted code by chance?